# Drawable.createFromStream taking longer with image from remote server?

Tags: java, android

It seems like Drawable.createFromStream is slower for an image requested from a remote web server vs. a local one. Does this make sense?

I have the following code to fetch an image from a web server via HTTP for an android app.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams httpparams = httpclient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpparams, CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout        (httpparams, CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MS);

// For test only
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(strUrl)); 
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();

Log.w("getimage", "Time to get image was " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + "ms");

// Check response
if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
    {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();

    Log.w("getimage", "This is how many bytes we skipped: " + inputStream.skip(1000000));

    image = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, "src name");
}

Log.w("getimage", "Time to return from image call was " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-time) + "ms");
```

If I point to my local site (local network), the first timer log is 30ms (HTTP request), and the second is 66 ms (HTTP request, plus drawable object).

If I do the same thing, but point to my web server, I get 298ms (expected it to be slower...), but then 1800ms for the HTTP request and drawable object call.

This tells me that the Drawable.createFromStream method is taking a whopping 1.5 seconds longer with the remote web server?

Any ideas on this? Is it performing any HTTP calls? The documentation is sparse. Everything was gravy when running locally, but got really slow when going remote...

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of InputStream HttpClient returns, but  have you tried wrapping the response InputStream in, say, a BufferedInputStream?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately it doesn't seem to make much of a difference. It's like the createFromStream call is doing something over the wire...

Comment: Then perhaps try reading the input all at once yourself. Then pass it to the Drawable. For some examples see http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/08/convert-inputstream-to-string-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it was the over the wire time that was killing me. Nothing I could do about this, so instead of getting each image serially, I instead use a thread per image (5 images max), and get them in parallel.

Something like...

```
m_threadLatch = new CountDownLatch(m_story.photos_thumb.length);
for(int i=0; i<m_story.photos_thumb.length; i++)
    {
    new HTTPGetImages(((MyApplication)getApplication()).getBaseURL() + m_story.photos_thumb[i]).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }
new AddImagesToUI().execute();
```

AddImagesToUI waits on the m_threadLatch, and adds the images to the UI. Result? Less than a second! Thank god for parallelism!